# Getting c++ exception trying to scrape javascript rendered web page with rvest and V8

Tags: r, web-scraping, v8, rvest

I want to scrape a webpage that is javascript rendered so rvest alone doesn't do the work I want. I am familiar with RSelenium but I don't want to use it for this task since I want to scrape multiple pages and it takes time. I am not familiar with V8 but I used [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/11/when-rvest-is-not-enough/) page as a guide to come up with this code.

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)

ctx <- v8()

link <- "https://www.pff.com/nfl/players/Drew-Bledsoe/36"

link %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('script') %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  gsub('document.write','',.) %>%
  ctx$eval() %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_text()
```

However this gives me an error:

```
Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context, serialize) : 
  c++ exception (unknown reason)
```

What I want to do is get the year value under draft year for some players. An example here would be 1993 in [this](https://www.pff.com/nfl/players/Drew-Bledsoe/36) page.

Answer (score 0):

If you read just two more paragraphs of the post you linked (and where you copied that snippet from), you'll find this statement:

> What is really needed in these cases is a Headless Browser

V8 is an ECMAScript engine. It does not know anything about the DOM, or browsers. That one line, `gsub('document.write','',.)`, hints at that, but isn't nearly enough: V8 knows no `document` object, no `window`, no `XMLHTTPRequest` or `fetch()` API, and so forth. For making sense of websites, it really needs to work together with an HTML engine/renderer.

Comment: T hanks.A suitable headless driver in this case could be phantomjs in this case right?